# See result of System.loadLibrary/ the defined methods and classes?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, loadlibrary

I have an .so file that I successfully integrated into android studio and I can load the file by calling `System.loadLibrary`.

Is there a way I can see what methods and classes I can use now with this library loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how the library maps Java methods to native function pointers: it can do one or both of the following:

- Dynamic symbols that start with `Java_` are [mangled names for the class and method name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615).
- If the code uses RegisterNatives system call you will have to put a breakpoint on `env->RegisterNatives` and look at the surrounding code/arguments.

Comment: I am actually not sure. I just took this rust project and compiled it for target android and I loaded the .so file that this produced. Any chance you know where I can lookup how rust code can be translated into java?

Comment: I have never done Rust or Rust with JNI, but the same principle applies: look for calls to RegisterNative, look for functions with a Java_ prefix, probably with the `#[no_mangle]` attribute.